# Move from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb4_general_ci

Tags: 7, database

I'm in the prosess of moving several Drupal 7 sites from one hosting provider to another. It appears the new provider only supports utf8mb4_general_ci (MySQL 5.7.18). Is there a simple way to convert utf8_general_ci databases and start using utf8mb4 on existing D7 installs?

[I've looked into this old question.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/how-to-easily-convert-utf8-tables-to-utf8mb4-in-mysql-5-5)

[This documentation page tells to convert all database tables](https://www.drupal.org/node/2754539). Can the "Steps to convert MySQL tables" be performed without Drush?

[This comment is the most promising guide I’ve found so far (without Drush)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2754539#comment-11763506)

I have SSH access on both servers, but no Drush. I am also able to move the site to localhost (Mamp) if that makes anything easier. I will be updating all installs to the latest Drupal 7 versions (currently 7.54). Should I update before converting the database?

Comment: The hosting provider is now supporting utf8_general_ci with the newer MySQL version. Now I do not need to convert the database. D7 was moved without issues.Since the question is uprooted I won't delete it.